# Custom IExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, exceptionfilterattribute

I'm trying to get a custom `IExceptionHandler` to work with my Azure Function (C# class library). The idea is to have my own exception handler for unexpected exceptions that will contain my own in-memory trace log; to clarify, I **do** want these sent to the client browser and displayed to the user.

Details follow.

With this simple custom exception handler:

```
public sealed class CustomExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler
{
  public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
  {
    context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(
        context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            "custom message string"));
  }
}
```

I've tried to install it as such:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "works")]
    HttpRequestMessage req)
{
  req.GetConfiguration().Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
      new CustomExceptionHandler());
  throw new Exception("unexpected exception");
}
```

but when deployed, I just get the generic "operation failed" error message (e.g., XML-formatted from Chrome):

```
<ApiErrorModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Models">
  <Arguments xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails i:nil="true"/>
  <Id>dec07825-cf4e-49cc-a80e-bef0dbd01ba0</Id>
  <Message>An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID dec07825-cf4e-49cc-a80e-bef0dbd01ba0</Message>
  <RequestId>51df1fec-c1c2-4635-b82c-b00d179d2e50</RequestId>
  <StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
</ApiErrorModel>
```

If I turn on `Diagnostic Logs -> Detailed error messages` in the AF UI and try to ensure detailed error messages are always written:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "works")]
    HttpRequestMessage req)
{
  req.GetRequestContext().IncludeErrorDetail = true;
  req.GetRequestContext().IsLocal = true;
  req.GetConfiguration().Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler),
      new CustomExceptionHandler());
  throw new Exception("unexpected exception");
}
```

then I do get exception details, but still apparently handled by the builtin exception handler (XML-formatted from Chrome):

```
<ApiErrorModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Models">
  <Arguments xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" i:nil="true"/>
  <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails>Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Function1 ---> System.Exception : unexpected exception at ...</ErrorDetails>
  <Id>5e752375-002b-4ab7-a348-20edad64a3fe</Id>
  <Message>Exception while executing function: Function1 -> unexpected exception</Message>
  <RequestId>b6611456-f3f1-4591-97e4-920dae59b5ff</RequestId>
  <StatusCode>InternalServerError</StatusCode>
</ApiErrorModel>
```

so this is exposing the stack trace and exception message, but I don't have my in-memory trace log.

What I want to do is create the response message for unexpected exceptions myself. For example, this is what my custom error response looks like for an expected exception (JSON-formatted, from Postman):

```
{
  "message": "An error has occurred.",
  "exceptionMessage": "Could not find package `nito.bob`",
  "exceptionType": "Common.ExpectedException",
  "stackTrace": "   at ...",
  "log": [
    "Received request for jsonVersion=4, packageId=`nito.bob`, packageVersion=``, targetFramework=``",
    "Looking up latest package version for `nito.bob`",
    "No non-prerelease package version found for `nito.bob`; looking up latest prerelease package version",
    "No package version found for `nito.bob`",
    "Returning 404: Could not find package `nito.bob`"
  ],
  "requestId": "b2df08cb-1071-4e47-bd24-bf74152e4b2a"
}
```

This is just the basic `HttpError`-formatted exception (with details) that I augment with `log` and `requestId`. Since this is an expected exception, this is not being done in an `IExceptionHandler`; I'm just returning the `HttpResponseMessage`.

The fun part: my custom `IExceptionHandler` works *just fine* when hosting the AF locally. It just doesn't work [when deployed](https://stephenclearyrepro1.azurewebsites.net/api/works). If I take [the code](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/FunctionsExecutionContextRepro) and run it locally, I get back the response I expect (JSON-formatted from Postman):

```
{
  "Message": "custom message string"
}
```

Alternative approaches that won't work for me:

- Catching all `Exception`s and returning `HttpRequestMessage.CreateErrorResponse`. I'm already doing this for *expected* exceptions, and that works fine. This isn't a good solution for *unexpected* exceptions because I want the function execution to clearly be marked as "failed". Returning an `HttpResponseMessage` (even with a 500 status code) is treated by the AF runtime as "successful", and does not show as "failed" in the dashboard or logs (or presumably by App Insights, though I haven't explicitly checked that).

Comment: Great question - looks like it _is_ working though on your 'when deployed' link, I see the custom message string.

Comment: @garthmason: And so do I now. Interesting...

Comment: Interesting indeed. It's puzzling this didn't work at first. I have a theory, but it seems a bit far fetched, so I'll try to spend some time on a repro so I can test it out.

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this question?

Comment: @Bsquare: Sure! AF has changed a *lot* since I wrote this, so it may Just Work now for all I know, but an answer would be appreciated anyway!

Comment: since you've posted this, functions has started supporting dependency injenction, although i dont at all agree with you approach of creating your own exception handler

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute`.

Here is a simple code sample for how to implement the abstract class:

```
public class YourErrorHandlerAttribute : FunctionExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(FunctionExceptionContext exceptionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fn_name = exceptionContext.FunctionName;
        var fn_instanceId = exceptionContext.FunctionInstanceId;
        var ex = exceptionContext.Exception;

        // TODO: your logic here.
    }
}
```

Here is how to use it in your function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
[YourErrorHandler]
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "works")]
HttpRequestMessage req)
{
     // TODO: your Azure Function logic / implementation.
}
```

It behaves similarly to `ActionFilterAttribute` in ASP.NET MVC